# Using SDK from Android Rebuilds project with Android Studio (3.0)

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to make Android Studio (3.0) work with the SDKs from [the Android Rebuilds project](http://android-rebuilds.beuc.net/) (even though they are still only at api version 23)?

I've managed to make it at least accept the SDKs by running the SDK setup wizard without internet access (otherwise it will complain that "An existing android SDK was detected. The setup wizard will only download missing or outdated SDK components" and tries to download both the newer SDK version and Google's proprietary blobs). This makes it possible to start a project, but gradle still fails with "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' [...]" even though the project is set only to build for version 23.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Yuliwee: It's the only EULA- and proprietary-blob-free distribution of the SDK I am aware of